# Стоит ли выделять продукцию в отдельную сущность?

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Стоит ли в базе данных отделять готовую продукцию от комплектующих, или объединить их в одну сущность "предмет"? Упрощенно, оба варианта выглядят следующим образом:

Вариант первый, комплектующие, продукция, полуфабрикаты находятся в общей таблице "Предметы". Тип определяет, является ли предмет составным (собран на предприятии) или атомарным (комплектующее и прочее). Единственный ощутимый минус - скорость обработки запросов упадёт при разрастании таблицы, но при этом не плодятся сущности, бритва Оккама в действии.
[image: Вариант 1]
Вариант второй, товары, собранные на предприятии находятся в отдельной таблице
[image: Вариант 2]

Comment: Обычно не разбивают комплектующие и продукцию по отдельным таблицам. Есть одна общая номенклатура предметов (товаров/изделий, как вам удобно их называть). Одни предметы могут быть комплектующими или сырьём для других.

Comment: @Sergey Проблема ещё в том, что собирать из комплектующих можно ещё и полуфабрикат, и во втором случае возникает вопрос, в какую таблицу его отнести? И как наладить связь полуфабрикатов и готовых изделий?
В случае одной таблицы это все легко решается, хотя я понимаю, что это слегка громоздкий вариант.

Comment: Да какая разница фабрикат, швабрикат, изделение или товар? Всё это прежде всего товарно-материальные ценности в бухгалтерии, производстве, на складе. Сами прикиньте сколько вам в каком случае считать, когда потребуется какая-нибудь ведомость движения ТМЦ, где должны быть собраны все виды швабрикатов.

Comment: @Sergey я просто подумал, вы рекомендуете второй мой вариант. То есть первый вариант, когда всё в одной таблице и есть таблица "тип изделия", вполне себе имеет право на жизнь? Просто в ней будет очень много записей, кому-то будет интересен список комплектующих, кому-то список готовых к продаже изделий, всё это увеличит скорость обработки запроса.